# How to use Bootstrap tooltips with the Python WTForms library?

Tags: python, twitter-bootstrap, flask, jinja2, wtforms

I'm building a website using the (awesome) [Flask framework](http://flask.pocoo.org/) and the [WTForms plugin](https://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). I now want to use show a [Bootstrap tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) on focus of an input field ([working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pghapodg/)), but for this I have to give the input tag the `data-toggle` and `title` attribute as follows:

```
<input data-toggle="tooltip" title="tooltip on focus!" type="text" placeholder="Focus me!" name="thename"/>
```

So I simply added them to the expression:

```
{{ form.plotting_value(title='tooltip on focus!', data-toggle='tooltip', class='form-control') }}
```

The `title` attribute is no problem, but the `data-toggle` causes a

> TemplateSyntaxError: invalid syntax for function call expression

Does anybody know how I can add the `data-toggle` to the input field using WTForms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python doesn't like the hyphens, you can either give it a dictionary:

```
{{ form.example(**{'data-toggle': 'tooltip'}) }}
```

or, wtform's will helpfully decode an underscore to a hyphen:

```
{{ form.example(data_toggle: 'tooltip') }}
```